# How can "Force close" can be recognized

Tags: android, forceclose

I have a weird error, I am not able to find a force close error in my project. 
But when I submit the project to my client he says it gives a force close message. I am unable to find the force close.

Could somebody please tell me how I can check where the force close error is coming from and where it is preventing the user to use the application?

Comment: You can get the Logcat messages to see where the exception is occurring. It will give you an idea of where the Force close is coming

Comment: @Lucifer yeaa sorry i am improving it

Comment: that is good. it helps other users too :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method actually : [remote-stacktrace](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/), where all your error messages will be posted on your web server, or even you can modify the code and send error logs to your e-mail. It works great in my situation. I'm using this to send all logs to our server at work.

Answer (score 2):

There are many services that let you collect crash reports. Some of them are

[Bugsense](http://www.bugsense.com/)

[Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/)

[ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)

Answer (score 1):

Ask your client to install https://market.android.com/details?id=org.l6n.sendlog and run it when the FC occurs to send you the log file.